# Shadow a part of the Fragment hierarchy

Tags: android, robolectric

I am a newbie at robolectric unit testing, i have a fragment which i want to test, ex, ScreenAFragment. This has a hierarchy as below,

ScreenAFragment -> MyAppFragment -> MyLibFragment -> SherlockFragment.

There are 2 problems,

1. The MyLibFragment has some code which links to a database and does other stuff which don't need to be tested as a 'unit test case'.
2. This MyLibFragment reference is also causing a "PackageManager#NameNotFoundException"

How do I go about testing this? My initial thought was create a `ShadowMyLibFragment` and config my test case `@config(shadow={ShadowMyLibFragment.class})` to use this instead of the original class. Doesn't seem to be working at the moment, as it still seems to refer to the original library and throws the old error.

Any Solutions? I am using Robolectric 2.4 version.

Comment: Could you please post the exact stack trace for the exception you are receiving? Also useful would be any bit of code that relates to that stacktrace.

Comment: Added the stacktrace here [gist](https://gist.github.com/shrivatsas/46dc4de5e4cd8c26bb34). The reference to `at com.artoo.api.ArtooApi.getHomePreferences(ArtooApi.java:215)` is where it is not able to find a package. The code that is being executed is `c = context.createPackageContext(ArtooApi.HOMEPACKAGE,
     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` Where i am trying to create a context to get access to a sharedpreference defined in a 'parent' app. So this ArtooApi is what i referred to as MyLibFragment earlier, i would be happy to test a mock implementation of this and not the original class.